# Would malware on a blank dvd-r prevent the burning of an .iso?

Tags: iso

If the dvd-r can only be written to once, if malware gets on the dvd-r before I burn an iso to it, would the malware on the dvd prevent the burning from happening?

Comment: If you already have a project containing malware written to your DVD-R, how can you write an iso on top of it? Brasero would complain that the disk is not empty.

Comment: @RomanRiabenko  No project, just putting in blank dvd-r into infected computer and then potentially writing to the blank dvd-r itself, nothing else.

Comment: .... the malware writing to the dvd...

Comment: @88species Burn software burns *iso images* into the dvd, nothing else (unless is a project, then you choose the files yourself). If there's any malware, it would be in the iso image itself.

Comment: @88species Do you mean malware written to the space which is not occupied by your data like in your other question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611658/after-burning-an-iso-to-a-dvd-is-there-any-free-space-left-on-the-dvd

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks. When you say, "if there is any malware"... Do you mean if there is any malware on the dvd-r before the burn? That's what I am referring to. If malware gets on the iso or the finalized os, I know the checksums will be bad. But I am ONLY concerned about the free space. Also, I put an update above.

Comment: @RomanRiabenko Yes, same as other question. Also, I put an update above. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a DVD renaissance going on or what? Do computers still have DVD drives? Who is still going to use DVDs as a malware vector in 2020?

Comment: Please consider wording.  A blank DVD has no data, this is what the word *blank* is about, hence no malware. So,  if some software (maybe malware on its own) burns malware on it before you want to burn your data on it, then the DVD is no longer blank,  just you do not know it. And yes, you will not be able to burn it because it would not be the first session.

Comment: @rexkogitans Thanks. Not to sound argumentative, but to make a point... malware can infect/write to a "blank" usb by infiltrating it's firmware. With a dvd, I have no idea of the dynamics that make up a dvd. I assumed malware could write to the disc.

Comment: @rexkogitans I have to ask... You stated that "if some software, maybe malware on its own, burns malware on it (disc), before you want to burn your data on it...." Since a dvd does not have firmware (as I just read on another stack answer), where is the software/ malware going to write to on the blank dvd? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the stack post I was referring to: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175201/are-dvds-vulnerable-to-firmware-malware-and-assorted-questions#175216

Comment: @88species Technically, any software could write to the DVD the same way your favorite burning software does. Burning DVDs does not need special firmware or drivers or whatever, it is a pretty standardized process as soon as the drive is accessible per se.

Comment: @rexkogitans Ok. To play devil's advocate - if malware were written to the blank dvd-r, it seems quite possible that the "malware writing", (which would be the first write) would Not "finalize" the dvd, therefore leaving open the strong possibility that the iso could still be burned to the dvd Thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After burning an .iso to a dvd, is there any "free space" left on the dvd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611658/after-burning-an-iso-to-a-dvd-is-there-any-free-space-left-on-the-dvd)